# What is the shape of a white hole?

Tags: energy-conservation, field-theory

Would a white hole maintain local symmetry or be an infinitely expanding field of energy?

Comment: Re *semetry*? Do you mean *[symmetry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symmetry#Noun)*?

Comment: At the collapse of the event horizon what would we see as a black hole evaporates

Answer (score 1):

They are identical to black holes in every way except that they will occasionally release matter from inside. They should really just be thought of as time-reversed black hole, so you shouldn't expect a constant flow of light from them like a star.

[Here](https://www.space.com/white-holes.html) is a good article on white holes.

Are you looking for a mathematical description, or will this suffice?